# Compile error with compare function, C++ sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I wrote myself a compare function for sort().
It worked well when I put it this way.

```
bool comp(string a, string b)
{
    ...;
}

int main()
{
    sort(...,...,comp);
}
```

However, when I put all this inside a class, say:

```
class Test {

public:
    bool comp(string a,string b)
    {
        ...;
    }
    vector <string> CustomSort(vector <string> str) {
        sort(...,...,comp);
    }
};
```

There is a compile error "No matching function for call to 'sort ......'.

Why would this happen?

Comment: You should be using `bool comp(const string &a, const string &b)`, I think.  It doesn't affect the name lookup, but it surely affects the runtime efficiency (constructing and then destroying a new string for each argument on each comparison is relatively expensive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any nonstatic member function of class `X` has an extra argument - a reference/pointer to (`const`) `X` which becomes `this`. Therefore a member function's signature isn't such that can be digested by `sort`. You need to use `boost::bind` or `std::mem_fun` or `std::mem_fun_ref`. When using C++11, you can use `std::bind`.

```
std::sort(..., ..., std::bind(&Test::comp, this, _1, _2));
```

Come to think of it, the best solution in this case would be to make your comp function static, because it doesn't need `this` at all. In this case your original code will work without change.

Comment: Thanks a lot Armen :) Your reply is very informative. Making comp function static is the easiest way. And I'll need to learn more so that I could understand the concepts you mentioned.